# How can I find out how much memory is used by a specific component or class?

Tags: delphi, memory, components

Is it possible to retrieve the amount of memory that is used by a single component in delphi?

I'm downloading simple strings from the internet and I see that the memory usage is up to a gigabyte at by the end of the downloading process, but when I look at the saved file which contains everything I downloaded the file is only in the kilobyte range, clearly there is something going on with the components, even though I destroy them.

Example:

Edit:

```
procedure TForm1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var list: TStringList;
begin
  list:=TStringList.Create;
  list.LoadFromFile('10MB_of_Data.txt');
  list.destroy;
end;
```

How can I know that "list" as a TStringList is using 10 MB worth of space in memory?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you want this information for debugging purposes? (It certainly looks like the component has some memory issues...) I guess you are already aware of things like the global [`ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown) variable?

Comment: Interesting, how do I turn this On?

Comment: Simply set the variable to `true`.

Comment: You can get the size of a single instance of an object using it's `InstanceSize` property, but that won't tell you that it internally has allocated a `TStringList` that's now up to 14 million individual strings, or that it has a `TList` that is now containing a GB of objects allocated elsewhere. You need to ask a specific question about the "single component" (and name that component) if you want to get specific help here.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks. I think that for this particular project I wont be needing the exact information about the content of the component, only its estimate size.
Sure, my component does have a TStringList in it but I don't really need to know anything about the TStringList itself, only its owner.
If you understand what I mean. I will try InstanceSize and see what it does.

Comment: I tried InstanceSize. It was not what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: It's the size of an instance of a component, which is the amount of memory used by a single component. You apparently do need more than that, which is what I tried to explain in my last comment. :-)

Comment: Ken: "InstanceSize is not what you want", Xaid: "I tried InstanceSize and it was not what I wanted."

Comment: Show a complete program please. Otherwise this is just going to lead to fruitless speculation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan hahaha I laughed to that, looked stupid.
Should I edit my question in order write some code? or should I write it here in a comment?

Comment: Code doesn't work in comments. Has to be as a Q edit.

Comment: You can make a good estimate on a string list by iterating over the list and summing the string length. You also need to account for the string's metadata. And a little overhead for the memory manager. But I cannot imagine that helps solve the real problem.

Comment: If I understand the situation correctly, you have a buggy component that leaks memory. If you are the author of the component, or if you have access to the source code, you should try to fix it. Otherwise, you should contact the developer, if possible.

Comment: There are many options to assess the size of used memory: 1) Using FastMM features [link for examples](http://wiert.me/2009/07/29/delphi-fastmm-using-fastmm4-for-debugging-your-memory-allocations-part-1-introduction/) 2) Using Heap or Stack functions to determining changes of the available memory 3) Assess the size based on intuition...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think comparing the memory usage before and after is the way to go with this as there is no simple way of seeing what memory was allocated by a block of code after the fact... For example, with the string list above, the class itself will only take up a small amount of memory as it is made up of pointers to other allocations (i.e. the array of strings) and that itself is an array of pointers to to the actual strings... and this is a comparatively simple case.

Anyway, this can be done with FastMM with a function like follows...

```pascal
uses
  FastMM4;

function CheckAllocationBy(const AProc: TProc): NativeUInt;
var
  lOriginalAllocated: NativeUInt;
  lFinalAllocated: NativeUInt;
  lUsage: TMemoryManagerUsageSummary;
begin
  GetMemoryManagerUsageSummary(lUsage);
  lOriginalAllocated := lUsage.AllocatedBytes;
  try
    AProc;
  finally
    GetMemoryManagerUsageSummary(lUsage);
    lFinalAllocated := lUsage.AllocatedBytes;
  end;
  Result := lFinalAllocated - lOriginalAllocated;
end;
```

And can be used like so...

```
lAllocatedBytes := CheckAllocationBy(
  procedure
  begin
    list:=TStringList.Create;
    list.LoadFromFile('10MB_of_Data.txt');
    list.Free;
  end);
```

This will tell you how much your string list left behind (which interestingly I get 40 bytes for on the first run of repeated calls and 0 after which after consulting the usage logs before and after the call is two encoding classes created on the first call). If you want to check where leaked memory was allocated, it's simple to use FastMM to do that also (although I agree with the above that if it's 3rd party, it shouldn't be your problem).

Comment: Yes, comparing seems to be the best way to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Seems legit, except how would this work in a multi-threaded environment when another thread might also be increasing memory consumption at the same time?

Comment: Simply put... It wouldn't. If debugging, could freeze other threads before initial usage check to make sure (if that level of assurance is required)... Although that might result in locking anyway. Besides, it may be another thread that allocates the hemorrhaged memory on behalf of the code under test. The point is that we just don't know the inner workings of the component.

Comment: Just another thought. it might get worse when considering a component that wraps a library (like TPerlRegEx can for example?). I don't think memory allocated in this library will be visible from local memory manager too... although it will eat up the memory available to the process. Oh well. More food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: please, be patient, this is actually not exactly answer for your question, but it is too large for posting it in comment. This code was written and compiled using FPC, but it can give some estimations for you. May be somebody knows how to port it to the Delphi.

```
program project4;

uses
    SysUtils,
    Classes;

var
    p: Pointer;
    sl: TStringList;
var
    a: TFPCHeapStatus;
begin
    a := GetFPCHeapStatus;
    writeln('== 1 ==');
    //writeln(a.MaxHeapSize);
    writeln(a.MaxHeapUsed);
    //writeln(a.CurrHeapSize);
    writeln(a.CurrHeapUsed);
    //writeln(a.CurrHeapFree);

    GetMem(p, 1024);

    a := GetFPCHeapStatus;
    writeln('== 2 ==');
    writeln(a.MaxHeapUsed);
    writeln(a.CurrHeapUsed);

    sl := TStringList.Create;

    a := GetFPCHeapStatus;
    writeln('== 3 ==');
    writeln(a.MaxHeapUsed);
    writeln(a.CurrHeapUsed);

    sl.Add('To beer or not to beer? That is the question!');

    a := GetFPCHeapStatus;
    writeln('== 4 ==');
    writeln(a.MaxHeapUsed);
    writeln(a.CurrHeapUsed);

    Readln;
end.
```

and output:

```
== 1 ==
2448
2448
== 2 ==
3488
3488
== 3 ==
3568
3568
== 4 ==
3616
3616
```

And another test with large text file:

```
sl.LoadFromFile('tolstoy - war and peace.txt');

a := GetFPCHeapStatus;
writeln('== 4 ==');
writeln(a.MaxHeapUsed);
writeln(a.CurrHeapUsed);
```

Output:

```
== 3 ==
3568
3568
== 4 ==
8837104
4643776
```

File size: 3,1 Mb (3 280 005 bytes) (ansi encoding)

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, which is "How much memory does a **specific component** use?" with an example of adding some 10M strings to the stringlist as one example. You've created an empty stringlist, then added a single string of known length. Use that information to predict how much memory it will take if you add 10M random-length strings to the stringlist, please. (Not strings of the same length - random length strings.)

Comment: == 3 ==
3568
3568

== 4 ==
8837104
4643776

File "tolstoy - war and peace.txt", ansi encoding, size = 3,1 Mb.

Comment: That's not 10M random strings; that's one set of data of fixed size (3.1Mb). Repeat now 1M times with 1M other sets of data, and tell me the size of a `TStringList`. As I said in my comment to the original post, you can't do it because you need to know information about the data it contains at this moment. Read the intent of the original question, as well as the comments made to it.

Comment: @KenWhite It seems we are dose not understand each other :) My text file for test is set of 49839 "random" strings (forgive me, Leo Tolstoy!) I just have not any other text file with appropriate size (except DB dump about 3 Gb which can not be loaded into 32-bit application). Or you mean `for i := 0 to 1000000 do begin sl.LoadFromFile('file' + IntToStr(i)); {test memory} end;`?

Comment: @Abelisto The issue is that the real program is likely more complex, much more complex, and interleaves lots of heap allocations. So this technique won't work. And it's code for the wrong compiler. If you want to offer code that's not an answer, use a pastebin.

Comment: No, I mean "load 1 million different size text files of many, many different sizes, and see if you can use that information to predict the size of a TStringList without knowing in advance anything about the data it will contain". Without knowing about the data it will hold, the only information you can know about `TStringList` is what `InstanceSize` tells you, which is not what this question is asking. (It even says so in the comments.) It's like asking "How big is a book?" and trying to tell someone without knowing about the content of the book first. You can't.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question was: "Is it possible to retrieve the amount of memory that is used by a single component in delphi?" In my comment above there was a one of several possible solutions: compare used memory "before" and "after". I just posted example written on FP (I not using Delphi for a while unfortunately).

Comment: @KenWhite I am really confused :) Are you want to load to the one TStringList "1 million" text files? Or load files one by one into same (or different) TStringList? In any case, if you have a lot of text data it is not good idea to use TStringList to handle it (because of  inefficiency).

Comment: One million different text files, one at a time, into a TStringList. I've said it three times now. :-) The point is that you can't give a general answer that "a container component is <x> bytes in size" without specific knowledge about what's in the container at the time. (If you know you have a 1Mb text file to load into a `TStringList`, that doesn't make the `TStringList` 1Mb + `TStringList.InstanceSize`, because it depends on the number of individual strings that will be added from the file. So you can't say for sure what size the stringlist will be before the file is loaded.)

Comment: @KenWhite Just as a training task :) 1) Allocate buffer (if it allows by file size); 2) Load file into buffer: 3.a) High performance, but not satisfied to task (size is FileSize + LinesCount * SizeOf(Carinal)): scan file for #13 or #10 or #13#10 depends on file source and fill some another array by pointers to each string; 3.b) Scan file buffer each time when some line needed. This is a fairly fast operation even for the files about 2 GB allocated in the RAM.

Comment: But you **still have to it loaded first**, which is my exact point in the other 10 comments. :-) You **have to load specific content to know the specific size**. You cannot say "a TStringList is <x> bytes in size" without knowing the content of `Strings` first, other than the information you get with `TStringList.InstanceSize` (which I've said before). :-) I'm going to downvote this answer, because a) the question asked for Delphi and your answer isn't about Delphi, and b) I don't think it answers the question asked at all - I've said why many times, as did David. Sorry. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite No any problems. I am on this site not for rating but for knowledge and experience (and for helping to others of course) :) But if to assemble all my comments & answers we are have in the end: refuse using TStringList for such tasks; use simple memory buffer which can be mirrored to any data type/data structure. And for completed finish line: main question is not on memory usage by some component, but on selecting efficiency way to solve some task. Good luck! :)