# Memory Leak: Downloading a file with UrlMon in Delphi causes a memory leak

Tags: delphi, download

I am using the procedure URLDownloadToFile from the UrlMon in Delphi to download
data from the internet.

It works and it's fast, but when I look at the memory usage of my software it increased
everytime I download a simple page such as google.com.

Now of course memory usage increases because the downloaded data is stored in memory,
but shouldn't the memory chunk be replaced with new data next time I download something?

***Example:***
1. My software uses by default 1000kb of memory,
2. I download a 200kb file from the internet,
then by logic only 200kb is increased which translates to 1200kb of software memory
usage on my software.

**Theory:**
3. I download the same file again, and my software should still be using 1200kb of memory.

**Reality**
3. I download the file again, and my software bumps up to 1400kb.

Why is that? It confuses me a lot because URLDownloadToFile actually saves the downloaded
data to the drive, so one could only expect that there is actually no use of memory once
the downloaded data is saved to the harddrive.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Run the code in an infinite loop and see if system memory is exhausted or not. Quite possible that you are mis-diagnosing a leak.

Comment: Which column in Task Manager are you watching? or how are you getting this 1400kb figure?

Comment: `IF` there is a memory leak, then we'd need you to post the code for further analysis.

Comment: You should know how to detect memory leaks in your code. Read the first comments to [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622455/how-can-i-find-out-how-much-memory-is-used-by-a-specific-component-or-class)

Comment: 1. Show me code that you uses for file download.
2. Try MadExcept with "Resource leak problems" and run. 
3. Try other solutions for file downloading. Like INDY, or Synapse, or Overbyte ICS

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys.
Before I post code, should I post it in the original question or here on the comment.

I have tried Indy and CEF1 as well but they all seem to behave the same way.

Comment: Have a look at your old questions. You have asked this several times and you should find the answer there, where to post the code. On the other hand just think about, how the posted code will look like in a comment. That should answer this too.